# acessar dados da matriz estando em outra classe?

Tags: java

Tenho uma matriz numa classe chamada Logica.

E estou manipulado ela de outra classe chamada Jogo.

Porém quando passo um valor da classe Jogo para a matriz na classe Logica e checo se o valor foi guardada na matriz ele me retorna 0, como se não tive "salva" na matriz .

Eu tenho que deixar a matriz na classe principal para que ela nunca perca e aceita os valores passados?

classe Jogo

```
public class Jogo {
 Logica logi =  new Logica();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    //exibe Tabuleiro :) 
    new Tabuleiro();        

 }

    public boolean validaJogada(int lin, int col){        
    if(logi.devolveValor(lin, col) != 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Valida Jogo Classe:JOGO " +logi.devolveValor(lin, col));
        return true;
    } 
 }

public void realizaJogada(int lin, int col, int jogador){
   logi.recebeJogada(lin, col, jogador);
   System.out.println(montaMatriz());

}

public String montaMatriz(){
    String matriz;
    int tabu[][] = new int [3][3];
    tabu = logi.devolveTabuleiro();

    matriz = tabu[0][0]+"|"+tabu[0][1]+"|"+tabu[0][2] + "\n";

    for(int i=1; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j=2; j < 3; j++){
           matriz += tabu[i][j]+"|"+tabu[i][j]+"|"+tabu[i][j] + "\n";
        }
    }

    return matriz;      

}
```

classe Logica

```
public class Logica {
public int tab[][] = new int[3][3];
private int jogador;


public int[][] devolveTabuleiro(){
   int i,j;

   for(i=0; i <=2 ; i++){
       for(j=0; j<=2; j++){
           System.out.println(this.tab[i][j]);
       }
   }

   return tab;
}

public boolean recebeJogada(int lin, int col, int jogador){        
    tab[lin][col] = jogador;   

    System.out.println("Recebi: col: " + col + " Linha: " + lin+ " do Jogador: "+ jogador);


    return true;
}

public int devolveValor(int lin, int col){
    return tab[lin][col];
}
```

O problema que está me ocorrendo nesse código é que toda vez que adiciono um novo valor a matriz ele perde os valores anteriores. É como se a matriz fosse criada toda vez que adiciono um valor.

o que será que estou fazendo de errado ??

Comment: Onde você ta chamando os métodos da classe `Jogo`?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve instanciar um objeto do tipo `Logica` na sua classe `Jogo`, então você poderá acessar a sua matriz. Exemplo:

Classe Logica:

```
public class Logica{
  //declara a matriz
  private String [][]matriz = new String[2][2];

  public void setarValor(int x, int y, String valor)
  {
      matriz[i][j] = valor;
  }

  public String[][] retornaMatriz()
  {
      return matriz;
  }

  public String retornaValorPosicaoMatriz(int x, int y)
  {
      return matriz[x][y];
  }
}
```

Classe Jogo:

```
public class Jogo{
  //declara objeto de logica, podendo assim acessar a matriz
  Logica logica = new Logica();

  //seta valores na matriz
  logica.setarValor(0,0,"X");

  //obtem a matriz de retorno
  String matriz[][] = logica.retornaMatriz();

  //obtem o valor de uma posicao da matriz
  String valor = logica.retornaValorPosicaoMatriz(0,0);

  //obtem o valor de uma posicao da matriz, outra forma
  String valor2 = matriz[0,0];
}
```

Comment: estou seguindo isso, mas acredito que devo estar fazendo algo errado. pq após setar uma valor para a matriz e chamo aqla posição ela aceita. porém quando set outro valor numa posição diferente retorna a matriz com o ultimo valor que "setei", como se apagasse os outros valores.

Comment: vou está pedindo de mais se lhe pedir para analisar meu código ? é que já não sei mais o q fazer para corrigir isso ... :/

Comment: edita sua pergunta e coloca o codigo